# Ordenar por fechas GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes.

Estoy intentando ordenar un resultado agrupado y quiero obtener el último movimiento realizado por un cliente con un dni dado.

La idea es agrupar por dni y mostrar sólo la última consulta de cada cliente (dni).
**Haciendo una prueba con 6 registros de un mismo cliente** (la consulta real es con miles de clientes), no hay forma de que me muestre la última consulta de cada uno, me muestra siempre la primera de cada uno, en este caso la de fecha 2016-12-31 15:27:28.

El campo por el que ordeno es una fecha tipo DATE_TIME.

Las sentencias son las siguientes, donde obtengo el mismo resultado en las 4 variantes del GROUP BY.

¿Algún iluminado puede echarme una mano?

```
mysql> SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM base.tabla ORDER BY fecha ASC;
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| fecha               | cliente | dni       |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| 2016-12-31 15:27:28 |   17553 | 77889990A |
| 2017-01-01 19:09:53 |   17553 | 77889990A |
| 2017-01-01 19:36:44 |   17553 | 77889990A |
| 2017-01-11 01:35:35 |   17553 | 77889990A |
| 2017-08-27 09:51:38 |   17553 | 77889990A |
| 2017-08-31 13:07:34 |   17553 | 77889990A |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM (SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM base.tabla ORDER BY fecha ASC) as ultimos GROUP BY dni;
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| fecha               | cliente | dni       |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| 2016-12-31 15:27:28 |   17553 | 77889990A |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM (SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM base.tabla ORDER BY fecha ASC) as ultimos GROUP BY dni ORDER BY ultimos.fecha ASC;
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| fecha               | cliente | dni       |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| 2016-12-31 15:27:28 |   17553 | 77889990A |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM (SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM base.tabla ORDER BY fecha DESC) as ultimos GROUP BY dni ORDER BY ultimos.fecha DESC;
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| fecha               | cliente | dni       |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| 2016-12-31 15:27:28 |   17553 | 77889990A |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM (SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM base.tabla ORDER BY fecha ASC) as ultimos GROUP BY dni ORDER BY ultimos.fecha DESC;
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| fecha               | cliente | dni       |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| 2016-12-31 15:27:28 |   17553 | 77889990A |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM (SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM base.tabla ORDER BY fecha DESC) as ultimos GROUP BY dni ORDER BY ultimos.fecha ASC;
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| fecha               | cliente | dni       |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| 2016-12-31 15:27:28 |   17553 | 77889990A |
+---------------------+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo

**SOLUCIÓN:**
SELECT MAX(fecha) AS fecha,cliente AS cliente,dni FROM base.tabla GROUP BY dni ORDER BY fecha ASC;

No hace falta la subconsulta y por tanto tampoco el ORDER BY de la misma ya que el MAX obtiene el resultado mayor.

## ++IMPORTANTE++

## El problema está en la versión del MYSQL 5.7.18, con las versiones anteriores no hay problemas, la subconsulta ordena por lo que le solicitas.

Probado en las versiones 5.1.60, 5.5.40 y 5.6.37.#

Comment: `SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM base.tabla WHERE dni='77889990A'  ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1;`  es todo lo que tienes que hacer. También puede ser: `SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM base.tabla WHERE cliente=17553  ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Prueba `SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM (SELECT fecha,cliente,dni FROM base.tabla ORDER BY fecha DESC) as ultimos;`

Comment: Si quieres **sólo un registro** no veo la utilidad del `GROUP BY`, puedes ordenar en orden descendiente y poner `LIMIT 1`  para que te dé sólo el último registro.

Comment: Si solo tienes un cliente no haría falta @A.Cedano. Por lo que creo yo, esa tabla tendrá más clientes, así que si quiere diferenciar por número de cliente en un futuro tendrá que utilizar GROUP BY

Comment: No @PabloSimonDiEstefano, por eso hay un `WHERE cliente=17553` o  un `WHERE dni='77889990A' ` para diferenciar por cliente. `GROUP BY` es para diferenciar sí, pero cuando necesitas agrupar más de una fila, y aquí al parecer se quiere una sola fila, por lo que agrupar no tiene ningún sentido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez asi te funcione :

```
Select cliente, dni, MAX(CAST(fecha AS CHAR))
    from base.Tabla
    group by cliente, dni
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido la aplicación del MAX() sobre esta consulta: 

SELECT MAX(fecha) AS fecha,cliente AS cliente,dni FROM  base.tabla GROUP BY dni ORDER BY fecha ASC;

No hace falta la subconsulta ni el ORDER BY ya que el MAX obtiene el resultado mayor.
Así obtengo el registro ordenado por fecha el listado con la última consulta de cada cliente.
Me he quedado un poco sorprendo. Gracias por la ayuda ;)

Comment: Si quieres un sólo registro no entiendo por qué usar funciones de agregación @JorgeSantana. Aunque funcione no es la solución más óptima.

Comment: A. Cedano, puede que no me explicara con claridad, pero no quiero un solo registro, nunca he buscado eso, las pruebas las hacía obteniendo un solo registro, pero como se indica en el enunciado, la consulta debía obtener un listado de todos los clientes con su última consulta no su primera como me salía probando con el ORDER BY sobre subconsulta.

Comment: Según esta especificación dada no se requiere un solo registro : "La idea es agrupar por dni y mostrar sólo la última consulta de cada cliente (dni)."

Comment: MAX() tampoco respeta los datos de la fila mostrando otra relación si pidas algún dato a parte del que filtras por el valor máximo, no se corresponde con la fila.

Answer (score 1):

Si como dices en la pregunta quieres una sola fila, no hace falta usar `GROUP BY`, la cual se usa para agrupar. Otra cosa sería si necesitas datos de varias filas en una sola fila.

Para obtener el último registro basta con:

- aplicar un `WHERE`para diferenciar
- poner un orden descendiente
- limitar el resultado a un registro

Algo así:

```
SELECT fecha,cliente,dni 
FROM base.tabla 
WHERE dni='77889990A' 
ORDER BY fecha DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

O bien:

```
SELECT fecha,cliente,dni 
FROM base.tabla 
WHERE cliente=17553 
ORDER BY fecha DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hacen esas consultas es primero agrupar y luego ordenar. Por lo tanto, estas ordenando sobre un unico registro restante.

Prueba a hacer un group by tras la primera seleccion.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT fecha,cliente,dni 
    FROM base.tabla 
    ORDER BY fecha ASC
) AS sub
GROUP BY dni
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572110/order-by-date-and-time-before-group-by-name-in-mysql)